# Querying for indexOfArray from a two level nested array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, pymongo

I am just working with this structure of JSON :

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId("5a264ff8fa5bd87ed9562471"),
    'sections': [
          {
               fields: [
                      {
                           'field_name': "Something1"
                      },
                      {
                           'field_name': "Something2"
                      }, ...
               ]
          }, ...
     ]
}
```

Now I want to know the index of the dictionary in the 'fields' array which has the field_name "Something1". I tried a few bit of things, and the last thing I tried out was

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {'_id': ObjectId("5a264ff8fa5bd87ed9562471")}},
        {$project: {index: {$indexOfArray: ["$section.0.fields.field_name", "Something1"]}}}
    ]
)
```

And the result was

```
index = -1
```

whereas, what I am really looking for is

```
index = 0
```

Can you please help me out with a different method to get the index?

Comment: Try `{"$indexOfArray":[{"$let":{"vars":{"fields":{"$arrayElemAt":["$section",0]}},"in":"$$fields.field_name"}},"Something1"]}`

Comment: The query gives an unexpected token ILLEGAL near "$arrayElemAt"

Comment: My apologies. Special character were added when I formatted the code. Please try this one. `{$indexOfArray: [{"$let":{"vars":{"fields":{"$arrayElemAt":["$sections",0]}},"in":"$$fields.fields.field_name"}}, "Something1"]}`